# Multiplicity constraint violated. The role xxx of the relationship xxx has multiplicity 1 or 0..1

Tags: c#, entity-framework, data-binding

Ive seen this question asked a few times but I'm afraid I am just not understanding the answers.

In a nutshell, I have a Player that contains a property of type PlayerBaseballStat.  Its a 1 to 1 relationship.  PlayerBaseballStat has an `ICollection<BaseballStat>` property.  both PlayerBaseballStat and BaseballStat have PlayerId to join the relationships.

```
 public class Player
    {
        public Player()
        {
            // initialize with empty shell
            PlayerBaseballStat = new PlayerBaseballStat();
        }
        public int PlayerId { get; set; }

//other properties removed for brevity

        public virtual PlayerBaseballStat PlayerBaseballStat { get; set; }

    }

public class PlayerBaseballStat 
    {
        [Required, Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int PlayerId { get; set; }
        public virtual Player Player { get; set; }

//other properties removed for brevity
       public virtual ICollection<BaseballStat> BaseballStats { get; set; }

    }
public class BaseballStat : EntityBase
    {
        public int PlayerId { get; set; }
        public virtual Player Player { get; set; }
        public int Year { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(25)]
        [Required]
        public string StatName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public decimal StatValue { get; set; }


    }
```

The mappings are:

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<Player>()
            .HasOptional(p => p.PlayerBaseballStat);

        modelBuilder.Entity<PlayerBaseballStat>()
          .HasRequired<Player>(x => x.Player);

        modelBuilder.Entity<PlayerBaseballStat>()
            .HasMany(p => p.BaseballStats);

        modelBuilder.Entity<BaseballStat>()
            .HasKey(x => new { x.PlayerId, x.Year, x.StatName });

        modelBuilder.Entity<BaseballStat>()
            .HasRequired(x => x.Player);
```

The data access layer is a templated repository.  The multiplicity constraint violation occurs on a read operation.

```
public T Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where)
    {
        return dbset.Where(where).FirstOrDefault<T>();
    }
```

The actual read is

```
_playerBaseballStatsRepository.Get(x => x.PlayerId == playerId);
```

That translates to

```
dataContext.PlayerBaseballStats.FirstOrDefault(x => x.PlayerId == playerId);
```

I know I am missing something in the mappings but I just cannot seem to figure it out.  Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What code specifically is causing the issue? Is it when you update an existing entity, insert a new entity, or simply retrieving a specific entity? It would help if you could post some sample code too. I created a small demo app with the schema provided above (minus the EntityBase inheritance on the BaseballStat entity) and executed the following flawlessly:

```
var player = new Player()
    {
        PlayerBaseballStat = new PlayerBaseballStat()
        {
            BaseballStats = new Collection<BaseballStat>()
            {
                new BaseballStat()
                { 
                    StatName = "ERA", 
                    StatValue = 1.41M, 
                    Year = 2011
                }                                            
            }
        }
    };

    context.Players.Add(player);
    context.SaveChanges();
```

It could possibly be how you are initializing the object.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I added some additional information regarding when the error occurs and how it is caused.  It currently happens on a read operation.  I haven't tested an update/insert function yet.

Comment: Jason- I've tried to duplicate this issue by adding a class which mimics your templated repository pattern and everything still works with the schema that you've provided. My first thought is that the there is somehow a mismatch in your data that you're pulling back, that some of the records are out of sync. How is the data getting in your repository?

Comment: The data was blown in from an external source.  Its possible that the data is part of the problem.  In the meantime, I removed the PlayerBaseballStat from the player object since its only needed for some admin functions and not for the rest of the application.  I will revisit this issue later as I have a very tough deadline (baseball season)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are initializing PlayerBaseballStat in the Player constructor. Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20198901/issue-loading-child-entity-of-a-parent-entity-unidirectional-mapping-and-1-to-0)

This needs to go away:

```
// initialize with empty shell

    PlayerBaseballStat = new PlayerBaseballStat();
```