# Issue loading child entity of a parent entity. Unidirectional mapping and 1 to 0..1 relationship with a Shared primary Key?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-ctp5

When I try to load child entity of parent entity it loads with default values. If i try to load explicitly it throws exception
**Multiplicity constraint violated**. The role 'Association_Customer_Target' of the relationship 'CodeFirstNamespace.Association_Customer' has multiplicity 1 or 0..1. This exception is thrown while retrieving the child entities of a complex graph.

I have a graph **Association** which has a child entity **Customer** with a relationship of **one to zero or one** and has an **Independent association**.**Primary key** is **shared**. I'm using EF6. lazy loading is enabled.

```
public class Association
{
   public virtual long Id { get; set; }
   public virtual string ExternalId { get; set; }
   public virtual int OrganizationId { get; set; }
   public virtual AssociationType AssociationType { get; set; }
   public virtual Customer Customer {get; set;}
   public Association()
   {
       Customer = new Customer();
   }
}
```

Customer class.

```
public class Customer
{
  public virtual long Id { get; set; } //Shared primary key
  public virtual ICollection<Item> Items {get; set;}
  public virtual ICollection<Complaint> Complaints {get; set;}
  public customer()
  {
    Items = new List<Item>();
    Complaints = new List<Complaint>();
  }
}
```

Mapping are Uni directional:

```
public class AssociationMapping:EntityTypeConfiguration<Association>
{
   public AssociationMapping() : base()
   {
     HasKey(x => x.Id);
     Property(x => x.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
     Property(x => x.ExternalId).IsRequired();
     Property(x => x.OrganizationId).IsRequired();
     Property(x => x.AssociationType);
     HasOptional(x => x.Customer).WithRequired().WillCascadeOnDelete();
   }
}

public class CustomerMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Customer>
{
  public CustomerMapping ():base()
  {
    HasKey(x => x.Id);
    Property(x => x.Id);
    HasMany(x => x.Items)
       .WithOptional()
       .HasForeignKey(key => key.CustomerId)
       .WillCascadeOnDelete();
    HasMany(x => x.Complaints)
      .WithOptional()
      .HasForeignKey(key => key.CustomerId)
      .WillCascadeOnDelete();
  } 
}
```

When I Load My association entity it loads perfectly but child entity Customer is loaded with default values when i try to load Customer explicitly it throws the exception.

```
 var dbassociation = Single<Association>(x => x.OrganizationId== asso.organizationId && x.ExternalId == asso.ExternalId && x.AssociationType == asso.AssociationType);
 dbassociation.Customer = Single<Customer>(x => x.id == dbassociation.id);
```

[Update: Single Method]

```
public TEntity Single<TEntity>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>criteria) {
  return Context.Set<TEntity>().SingleOrDefault(criteria);   }
```

For testing purpose I have tried to eager load by removing virtual on Customer property in association class and tried following but it throws same excepetion

```
Context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
Context.Entry<Association>(dbassociation).Reference<Customer>(pa => pa.Customer).Load();
```

I have also tried which throws same exception

```
var dbassociation = Context.Set<Association>().Include("Customer").SingleOrDefault(x => x.OrganizationId== asso.organizationId && x.ExternalId == asso.ExternalId && x.AssociationType == asso.AssociationType);
```

Now I came to conclusion that though I use different methods for retrieving the exception is same. The problem is with mapping I guess. I appreciate your comments and suggestions.

Comment: What exactly is the relationship between `Association` and `Customer`? Is it 1:1, one-to-many, etc? Which table has the FK reference?

Comment: I have already mentioned it is 1:0..1 Primary key is shared between association and customer. Customer has the fk reference.

Comment: Removing `virtual` keyword from Navigation Property doesn't mean eager-loading.

Comment: What I intend to meant was after removing virtual I followed the next steps to make eager loading work. Which did not.

Comment: How does `Single<T>` method looks like?

Comment: Try to remove `Customer = new Customer();` from the `Association` constructor. It is the reason why you get a customer with default values. However, I'm not sure if it's also the reason for the exception.

Comment: This is working.But I don't know if it have any impact on other parts. What is the theory behind not instantiating the Customer object in the constructor when working with EF/ORM? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Mady: Instantiating navigation references in the default constructor has only negative impacts (instantiating navigation collections is fine though). I've seen other examples where this causes weird issues and you won't see any official example or EF autogenerated code where this is done. I don't have a good explanation. Let me revert the question: What is theory behind instantiating a customer object in the constructor (with default values it's meaningless) and what benefit do you expect? :)

Comment: I got it Thanks.How would I vote your comment as answer?

Comment: @Mady: You can't accept comments as answers. I have added an answer now with some more hypotheses.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try to remove

```
Customer = new Customer();
```

from the `Association` constructor. Instantiating navigation references is a source for known problems (in contrast to instantiating empty navigation collections which is fine). It is the reason why you get a `Customer` with default values. I'm not sure if it also explains the exception, but I could imagine that when the `Association` gets loaded and attached to the context together with the uninitialized `Customer` created by the default constructor EF detects related entities with invalid keys: The `Association` which has (I assume) a key value `!=0` and the related `Customer` with a key `==0` (because it never has been initialized to another value). However, in a shared primary key association the two key values must match. Because they don't, it might cause the exception (however an exception that doesn't really point very well to the root of the problem).

Just a guess.